# ScrollPane with preferedViewportWidth matching preferedWidth of content

Tags: javafx-2

I have a bunch of [regions](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) which have a specific preferedWidth set. These Regions are reused visual components in a drag and drop UI.

I want to create a conatainer of these regions and tried to accomplish this with a ScrollPane with an embedded VBox. I want the scrollpane to be wide enough to hold the VBox without horizontal scrolling.

I could figure out the width of the VBox by hand and hardcode the scrollbars width but i would prefere a dynamic solution so that i can style the vbox later. Unfortunately the vbox preferred width is -1 even though its children have a prefered width set.

Also if i try to set the scrollpanes preferedViewportWidth to the width of my regions i get mixed results dependent on the hbarPolicy. If the policy is set to AS_NEEDED the width of the scrollbar is ignored and the scrollbar appears over my regions when it appears.

Any ideas how i get a SrollPane which is wide enough for my regions with and without a vertical scrollbar and possible styling of paddings etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by binding the ScrollPane's `prefViewportWidthProperty()` to the width property of the child.